# How do I insert the table of contents outside the main page content region in a custom mediawiki skin?

Tags: mediawiki, skin, tableofcontents

When creating a mediawiki skin how would I go about putting the table of contents on a sidebar outside of the main page content area?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the TOC is not printed out, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NoTOC

Then I would suggest you copy the relevant parts of [Parser::formatHeadings](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classParser.html#adb535b95c220c651538833f484027c02) to your skin, to create a TOC where you want it.

However, unless you really, really need it to appear outside the article for all users, I think it would be much easier to use Javascript to move #toc where you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the Table of Contents to be on the side but remain available regardless of the user's scrolling position, you could use the CSS property `position: fixed` (the following worked for me for MW 1.24.4 with the default Vector skin, as well as for the built-in MonoBook, Modern, and Cologne Blue skins):

```css
#toc {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 7em; /* 5em is height of header, 6em brings just under */
    /* bottom: 5em; /* 5em puts us above the footer; not bad but too low when TOC is collapsed */

    z-index: 10000; /* Ensure we float above the header, etc. */

    /* Add opacity (translucency) */
    background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    background-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.9); /* Higher opacity (last arg) means less transparency */
}
/* Ensure the TOC height doesn't take over the screen; percentages may be higher than view port, so we use pixels */
#toc > ul {
    max-height: 350px;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```